# How to blur image in browsers that don't support CSS3 filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a blurred image is one of the main aesthetic features on my website. So far I am using CSS3 filter blur() to create the blur, but I know this is not supported in neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer. I was wondering is there an alternative, maybe JavaScript/jQuery, which will help me create the blurred effect I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of JS libraries that blur images.

- [BlurJS](http://www.blurjs.com/)
- [VagueJS](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js)
- [StackBlur Algorhythm](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html)

Anyway, if you're using a static blurred image (i.e., no need to unblur/blur it again), I'd say you should go with a normal bitmap image. That might help to avoid unnecessary CPU load on the browser and compatibility issues.

Comment: It will be a dynamic image from an external source so the only way forward for me I'm afraid is Javascript/jQuery. I will definitely check out the above, they look like they'll do the job!

Comment: @JamesWalker Seems legit. Good luck with your project :) And, if any of the answers here helped you, please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

See if [blur.js](http://www.blurjs.com/), a jQuery plugin, does the trick for you. Essentially, what it does is move your image to a `<canvas>`, and does the blurring effects there. See a more comprehensive article on the topic: [Effects for the Web!](http://drublic.de/blog/effects-for-the-web/).